# ROR build inserting mutiple records at a time by form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

[Form screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2HVn2.png)

the image up explain that there is employ who has been allocated three projects at this time he want to full up the fields as he want example he can fill up 2 fields and press submit btn or 1 or 3 depending how many projects he has been assigned.

what i was unable to do is that i want to insert that multiple fields in a table in single submit i do not understand what code i write it will work 
the code in my controller is the following.

```
def new  
  @pro=Employee.find(params[:employee_id])
  @timesheet=Timesheet.new
  @project=Project.where(:employee_id => params[:employee_id]).sorted
end

def create
  @pro=Employee.find(params[:employee_id])
  @timesheet=Timesheet.new(params.require(:timesheets).permit(:employee_id,:project_id,:IN,:comments))

  if @timesheet.save
    flash[:notice] = "data entered."
    redirect_to(:action => 'show',:employee_id =>@pro.id)
  else 
    flash[:notice]="logged out"
  end
end
```

the code in my new.html.erb is the following

```
<%= form_for(:timesheets, :url => {:action => 'create',:employee_id => @pro.id}) do |d| %>
    <% if !@project.nil? %>
        <% @project.each do |page| %>
            <tr>
                <%= d.hidden_field("employee_id" ,:value => @pro.id) %>
                <%= d.hidden_field("project_id" ,:value => page.id) %>

                <% if !page.employee_id.blank? %>
                    <td><%= page.prog_name %></td>
                    <td><%= d.text_field("IN",:class => "qty1") %></td>
                    <td><%= d.text_field("comments") %></td>
                <% end %>
            <% end %>
        </tr>
    <% end %>

   <tr>
       <td>Total hours</td>
       <td colspan="2"><%= text_field_tag("total")%></td>
   </tr>
   <tr border="0">
       <td ><%= submit_tag("Submit") %></td>
       <td colspan="2" border="0"></td>
   </tr>
```

Comment: One thing that should be changed is that in your view code, you are closing the `@project.each do |page|` loop before you close the `<tr>` tag inside of it.

Comment: ok sir i will do that but how to do what i ask up there

Comment: Look into `fields_for`, it allows you to include fields for child associations in a rails form.  Also, `accepts_nested_attributes_for` is needed to allow for saving changes to the child attributes.